# rjust() inside __str__() not working in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model class with `level` and `name` fields (it's about subcategories levels).

I want to display the name of each row with corresponding number of dashes indent in the select dropdown in the admin panel.

When I use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name.rjust((self.level-1) * 4, '-')
```

in the Django model, it doesn't work and keeps showing me the name without the dashes.

If I use the same code in a pure Python script, it does work. Debug showed that `self.level` has correct value in the `__str__()` Django function.

Why it doesn't work in Django?

Update: I fixed it with the obvious:

```
def __str__(self):
    indent = '-' * (self.level-1) * 4
    return indent + self.name
```

However, the question why it doesn't work in Django is still open.

Comment: Your 2 examples aren't the same. `rjust` doesn't insert the number of fill characters you specify, it inserts the number needed to fill out that total length. If `self.nane` is long enough, it will be returned unchanged.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Stupid me. Of course, it is ```self.name.rjust((self.level-1) * 4 + len(self.name), '-')```. Please, answer the question and I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and I have done so. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 examples aren't the same. `rjust` doesn't insert the number of fill characters you specify, it inserts the number needed to fill out that total length. If `self.name` is long enough, it will be returned unchanged